# Notation for directional derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, vector-analysis

I know if $\vec u$ is a unit vector, then $\triangledown(x,y) \bullet \vec u$ is the directional derivative, or $D_{u}(a,b)$

However, if $u$ is a vector, when $f_{\vec u}(a,b)$ is a real, what does it mean? $u_xf_x(a,b)+u_yf_y(a,b)$?

When it is a vector, what does it mean? $\langle u_xf_x(a,b),u_yf_y(a,b) \rangle$?

Comment: That would depend on where you saw this.

Comment: Apparently, $f_u(a,b)$ is sometimes a vector and sometimes a real, right?

Comment: You have to define it/give it meaning before that question can be answered.

Comment: Is this well defined? Any parts that are a bit ambiguous?

Comment: Yes, it is ambiguous.  You've written down two different things.  One is a scalar, and the other could be a vector, depending on whether $\langle x, y \rangle$ means a vector or an inner product.

Comment: The thing to do is *look within wherever you saw this for the answer.*  Different authors use different notation, but only horrible writers leave things undefined.

Comment: If $\exists$ the two partial derivative $f'_x$ and $f'_y$, you usually write $f_u(a,b)$ as $f_u(a,b)=u_1 f'_x(a,b)+u_2 f'_y(a,b)$, where $u$ is a vector whose components are $(u_1,u_2)$ and $||u||=1$. While $\langle u_1f'_x(a,b), u_2f'_y(a,b) \rangle$ defines the inner product of two vectors, which is a scalar since $\langle . , . \rangle :V \times V \to \mathbb{K}$ is a bilinear map.

Comment: Ok I think I got it. I just need to look at how the question is defined, and it's usually one of the two I said above.